# How can i find device type and name in linux terminal without install nmap and other similar tools from it ip address?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv4, arp

I'm looking for find a way to get device name and type like ESET Connected Home Monitor .

> Eset :
> Connected Home Monitor can help identify vulnerabilities in your home network such as open ports or a weak router password. It also provides you with an easy-to-access list of connected devices, categorized by device type (e.g. printer, router, mobile device, etc.)

https://help.eset.com/eis/13/en-US/idh_page_homenetwork_protection.html

[Eset Connected Home Monitor](https://help.eset.com/eis/13/en-US/images/page_homenetwork.png)

And this app can find device type as well you see in this image . it can find and and differentiate mobile devices , printers , pc and modems .

How can i find device type in linux terminal without install nmap and other similar tools from it ip address ?

I try to use host command but it does not give the desired results .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. the software you are comparing to likely has a mac address OUID database, scans for common services, and performs basic OS fingerprinting of the IP stack, which are all things that `nmap` does, but no single utility built into most distros would be capable of.

Comment: First using arp command find mac address of device . if these equals with first three octets of mac address of tp-link modems, then it will understand that device is tp-link modem. is right ?

Comment: yes, but a lot of devices will have nics built by manufacturers that are not the same as the brand of the whole device (an MSI laptop might have a nic from realtek), and there are lots and lots of nics out there using unregistered OUIDs, and MACs are often admin configurable or randomly generated. its a place to start, but provides extremely limited capabilities, leaves you with unanswered questions, and requires a lot of manual work. seriously, just download nmap. thats probably what eset did.